# Why might an HTTPS page request be faster than HTTP?

Tags: performance, http, https

[This article mentions](https://scotthelme.co.uk/still-think-you-dont-need-https/) and [this site seems designed to show](http://www.httpvshttps.com/) that HTTPS can be faster than HTTP. I'm surprised; I thought HTTPS was just HTTP plus encryption, which adds a small, [likely negligable](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2010/06/25/overclocking-ssl.html) amount of work but doesn't remove any.

**Why might an HTTPS page load be faster than one over HTTP?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a bit of a con to be honest.

HTTPS is slower than HTTP. There's no denying that. HTTPS works over HTTP so has to do everything HTTP does and more. Now, with good web server config, the computational cost of HTTPS is almost non-existent to the average user on today's modern hardware but it is there. But it also slows down the first page render as it takes a few hundred extra milliseconds to set up the HTTPS connection. Again not a big deal for most people but it is there.

Now there is the argument that someone - be it a mobile network or ISP or whatever - can change HTTP by injecting ads and the like, potentially slowing down a website, but that's not the reason for the speed difference here.

The reason that website is faster is because it is using HTTP/2 when using HTTPS and not when using HTTP. HTTP/2 is faster than HTTP/1.1 - especially for websites with lots of resources.

Of course you can say that HTTP/2 is only available over HTTPS and while that is true*, the corollary is not - implementing HTTPS does not automatically give you HTTP/2.

*Well technically it's not true that HTTP/2 requires HTTPS as per the spec, but all the browser makers have said they will only support this over HTTPS so it basically is true to all intents and purposes.

Additionally the sample website loads 360 small and near identical (but crucially not identical) resources. Precisely the sort of thing that HTTP/2 is very good at. And while average web pages are growing, most of them don't load 360 near identical images - so that network latency is basically the only bottleneck. Most have other issues as well that are nothing to do with the network latency issues that HTTP/2 massively improves.

The speed gains for HTTP/2 are hugely impressive and it is the future and everyone should use it, as latency **is** a major bottleneck. But that test site is an extreme example of it. Depending on the exact site's make up, HTTP/2 will mostly offset the cost of HTTPS and [in many cases more than offset it](https://blogs.akamai.com/2015/08/is-http2-worth-the-performance-price-of-tls.html) - but that does not mean HTTPS itself is faster.

There are very good reasons to use HTTPS, and the article is fantastic for listing them all (except for that first one). In my opinion HTTPS should be the default and everyone should move to it - precisely for the other reasons listed. But it's a lie to say HTTPS is faster that HTTP. Or, at the very least, it obfuscates the truth by not explaining why it *can* be faster. And then listing HTTP/2 as a second, seemingly unrelated, reason to further confuse the reader! I just don't understand why they couldn't combine these  two points into one and fully explain this so questions like this didn't need to be asked? Same for that sample site - why is there no FAQ to explain **why** HTTPS is apparently faster?

Answer (score 0):

Historically yes, https was http+ssl/tls, so it was slower

But now with spdy/http2, it's a new protocol, which can be faster than http when dealing with multiple requests:

- it can compress headers, and if you send the same header multiple times (like cookies) it doesn't need to send it fully but just an id
- if can reuse tcp connections, so it avoid the overload of opening multiple tcp connections and stream efficiently data

Comment: HTTP 1.x can also reuse connections for multiple requests, and also pipeline multiple requests over a given connection.

Comment: Not as efficiently as http2 as you can see.

Comment: True. But if an HTTPS 1.x connection were using these features, it could be faster than an HTTP 1.x connection that doesn't.

Comment: Pipelining in HTTP/1.1 is so poorly supported it might as well not exist. See here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining

Answer (score -1):

If you use some kind of network scanner (e.g. a component of an antivirus, proxy of firewall), it may scan plain HTTP traffic causing a slowdown. At the same time, it won't touch encrypted HTTPS traffic unless you installed a special root certificate that will help the intermediate scanner to process HTTPS traffic. So if there is some kind of intermediate service scanning HTTP traffic, but not HTTPS -- using HTTPS will be much faster.